# strange characters when I encode json

Tags: php, json

I have the following code which encodes json in php

```
$arr = array('htmlOutput' => $htmloput, 'no_rows' => 'blah');
    echo json_encode($arr);
```

$htmloput contains html mark up.

For some reason, there is a lot of \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t in the output. Also, do single quotes or double quotes in the markup cause any proples when you encode in JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those characters are text-representations of whitespace characters. `\r` is carriage-return. `\n` is newline. And `\t` is tab. Quotes shouldn't matter.

Some others (from the [string docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)):

- "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
- "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
- "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
- "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
- "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.